# Dynamically Implementing Section in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am not able to wrap my head around the implementation of sections in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

I have a `UITableView` in which I would like to show 2 sections.

- Incoming Friend Requests
- Friends

In Storyboard, I change my `UITableView` `Style` to `Grouped`.

Next, I would like there to be no `Friend Request` section if there are no friend requests. In `viewDidLoad`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    (...)
    if friendRequests.isEmpty {
        friendsDataSource = friends
    } else {
        friendsDataSource = [friendRequests, friends]
    }
}
```

The rest:

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return friendsDataSource.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return friendsDataSource[section].count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {        
    let friendRequest = friendsDataSource[0][indexPath.row]
    let friend = friendsDataSource[1][indexPath.row]

    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FriendCell") as? FriendCell {
        cell.configureProfileCell(userProfile)
        return cell

    } else {
        return FriendCell()
    }
}
```

I know my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is disgusting but I have absolutely no idea how to implement it.

Any help in the right direction, greatly appreciated

Comment: Where you have hard coded 0 and 1 in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you should use `indexPath.section` and only deal with one cell at a time - either  section 0 or section 1

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So `[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]`? @Paulw11

Answer (score 2):

Discovered `if (indexPath.section == 0)`, and I just hacked around that.

My eyes hurt looking at this so Please post better ways of doing this. For now:

```
var friendRequests = [FriendRequest]()
var friends = [UserProfile]()

var friendsDataSource = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    friends = FriendManager.instance.myFriends
    friendRequests = FriendManager.instance.incomingFriendRequests

    if friendRequests.isEmpty {
        friendsDataSource = [friends]
    } else {
        friendsDataSource = [friendRequests, friends]
    }
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return friendsDataSource.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return friendsDataSource[section].count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FriendCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? FriendCell {

        if friendRequests.isEmpty {
            let friendCell = friends[indexPath.row]
            cell.configureProfileCell(friendCell)
        } else {
            if (indexPath.section == 0) {
                let friendRequestCell = friendRequests[indexPath.row]
                cell.configureRequestCell(friendRequestCell)
            } else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
                let friendCell = friends[indexPath.row]
                cell.configureProfileCell(friendCell)
            }
        }
        return cell
    } else {
        return FriendCell()
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, inspecting `indexPath.section` is the correct way to dynamically determine how to configure cells for different table sections.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the other, newer dequeueing method: `dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier(_:forIndexPath:)` instead (passing the actual index path).

That one is guaranteed to always succeed, so you can do without this `if/else` structure:

```
if let cell = ... {
    ...

    return cell
}
else {
    return FriendCell()
}
```

By the way, you are returning the `FriendCell` instance fresh, without configuring it. Is that what you really want?

**Clarification**
The method `dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier(:)` succeeds only if there is one or more cells with the specified identifier already enqueued for reuse; the first few times you call it it will return nil and **you need to fallback** to instantiating a new cell (with the same identifier), for immediate use (and later reuse):

```
func tableView(tableView:UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath:NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    if let cell = tableView.dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier("Identifier") as? FriendCell {
        // Successfully dequeued for reuse;
        // configure it:

        // (set labels' texts, etc.)

        return cell
    }
    else{
         // No cell enqueued; create anew

         let cell = FriendCell(style:.Plain, reuseIdentifier:"Identifier")

         // configure it

         // (set labels' texts, etc.)

         return cell
    }
}
```

...But because this check is a pain, Apple added a new method:

```
dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier:String, forIndexPath:NSIndexPath)
```

that internally performs the dequeueing and **also initializes a new cell if no one is available**. This eliminates the need for an else path in the code above, and it gets smarter:

```
func tableView(tableView:UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath:NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier("Identifier", forIndexPath:indexPath) as! FriendCell
    // (Never fails - provided identifier is right and class is registered for it)

    // configure it:

    // (set labels' texts, etc.)

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I edited my code with `forIndexPath`, not sure if how I did it, is how you were suggesting, but please take a look and let me know. Also, what do you mean by 'returning the `FriendCell` instance fresh'?

Comment: By 'fresh' I mean that you just create a new instance but do not configure any of its properties (return it 'blank').

Comment: Is that not how to do it? Because if it is successfully dequeued, I am returning a configured `FriendCell` as opposed to a fresh one.

Comment: Dequeueing successful or not, the table view expects you to return a fully configured cell for display.

Comment: That's what it is doing. What do you suggest? I'm confused

Comment: You are returning an **empty, blank** cell.

Comment: `if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FriendCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? FriendCell {`  has always succeeded for me. If a `FriendCell` can't be dequeued, it returns an empty, blank cell, which has never happened once. I have no idea what you're talking about. If you're not willing to show me what you mean, this is useless

Comment: awesome! This indeed greatly simplifies things. Thanks a bunch !