# Different UITableViewCells overlapping

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with 3 prototype cells and 3 custom cell classes: 
`FriendCell`
`FriendRequestCell` and `AddFriendCell`.

Initialized, the table displays `Friends`.

If there are any `FriendRequests`, it displays them in the section above `Friends`.

If there are no `FriendRequests`, it only displays `Friends`.

[image]

However, I also have a `UISearchBar` that searches for users and when it has results, should return `AddFriendCell`s and reload the table.

Instead, I get this:

[image]

Code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if searching == true {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("AddFriendCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? AddFriendCell {
            let resultCell = userResults[indexPath.row]
            cell.configureCell(resultCell)
        }
    } else {
        if friendRequests.isEmpty ||  (indexPath.section == 1)  {
            if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FriendCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? FriendCell {
                let friendCell = friends[indexPath.row]
                cell.configureCell(friendCell)
            }
        } else {
            if (indexPath.section == 0) {
                if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FriendRequestCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? FriendRequestCell {
                    let friendRequestCell = friendRequests[indexPath.row]
                    cell.configureCell(friendRequestCell)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return FriendCell()
}


func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    if searching == true {
        return 1
    } else {
        return friendsDataSource.count
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if searching == true {
        return userResults.count
    } else {
        return friendsDataSource[section].count
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    if searching == true {
        return nil
    } else {
        if friendsDataSource.count > 1 {
            if section == 0 {
                return "Friend Requests"
            } else if section == 1 {
                return "Friends"
            }
        } else {
             return "Friends"
        }
        return "Friends"
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    if searching == true {
        return 0
    } else {
        return 25
    }
}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searching = true
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    userResults = [UserProfile]()
    activitySpinner.startAnimating()

    if let searchText = searchBar.text {
        let userProfileQuery = PFQuery(className: "UserProfile")
        userProfileQuery.whereKey("username", containsString: searchText)

        userProfileQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ resultArray, error in
            if error != nil {
                print("there's been an error searching for users: \(error)")

            } else if let resultArray = resultArray {
                print("number of results: \(resultArray.count)")
                self.parseResults = resultArray

                for userProfile in resultArray {
                    let username = userProfile["username"] as! String
                    let profilePicUrl = userProfile["profilePicUrl"] as! String
                    let parseObjectId = userProfile.objectId!

                    let newProfile = UserProfile(username: username, profilePicUrl: profilePicUrl, parseObjectId: parseObjectId)
                    self.userResults.append(newProfile)
                }
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                self.activitySpinner.stopAnimating()
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Any ideas on the root of the problem?

Comment: This probably has to do with the size of the cell you're trying to dequeue. Since you're dequeueing a different kind of cell,  your `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat` implementation should return different size according the to kind of cell you're using.

Comment: @Champoul I haven't touched cell sizes in my code. Does it need to be addressed?

Comment: do your cells have different heights ?

Comment: IMO it also seems that your code is a bit over complex. Why have 3 different kind of cells for a cell who's UI is almost the same. Same thing could be achieved with one cell class whose UI is layed out according to its type.

Comment: @Champoul because the UIs will evolve over time. And no they don't have different heights!

Comment: from the screenshot, looks like there is an offset issue. If it's not height, what about section headers ? they don't seem visible while you search.

Comment: @Champoul Ok I just added the rest of the relevant code

Comment: ok seems to be fine. what about the search related code ?

Comment: @Champoul Just added it

Comment: On what thread are you performing your reload data ? seems like you're getting a callback from a background thread after calling `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock`. adding a `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue, ^{})` should improve the behavior of your app. you're also retaining your self object by referencing it in an async callback.

Comment: @Champoul Gonna try that now. In the meantime, what do you mean by 'retaining your self object by referencing it in ....`

Comment: @Champoul Ok I wrapped `self.tableView.reloadData()` in a `dispatch_async` as you suggested. Still getting the same result though.

Comment: In ObjC, blocks, or closures in swift, will retain retain any value that are captured when they are created. Since you're referencing "self" in your closure, it will be retained and could result in a retain cycle. The workaround in this case is to create what we call a weak reference on your object and use it in your closure. This will avoid the retain cycle and send the messages if the object has not been dealloc. `__weak id weakSelf = self;` is the variable you should be using.

Comment: @Champoul I got really lost with your last comment. I have never seen code beginning with `__` before. I just want to reloadData in the closure. It can't be that complicated. Furthermore, does this address the cells overlap?

Comment: What about making your cell hidden when cell height meets zero?

Comment: @EricJohnson nothing to do with complexity. This is just good objective-C coding practices.  Never assign a self property elsewhere than main thread, never do UI updates elsewhere than the main thread, never reference self in a closure / block.

Comment: @Champoul just letting you know the question is in Swift, and the official Apple documentation instructs you to use self. in closures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here is the code for multiple types of cell:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if searching == true {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("AddFriendCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AddFriendCell

        // ...configure your cell...

        return cell 
    } 
    else{
        if friendRequests.isEmpty ||  (indexPath.section == 1)  {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FriendCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FriendCell

            // ...configure your cell...

            return cell            
        } 
        else{
            if (indexPath.section == 0) {

                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FriendRequestCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FriendRequestCell

                 // ...configure your cell...

                return cell
            }
            else {
                // Decide what to do if section is NOT 0. If this CAN happen
                // and you don't have a cell type to return, it is a design flaw.
                // don't add a adummy "return FriendCell()" as a fallback for a
                // case that should never happen, to make the compiler happy. 
                // This type of error should be caught during development.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(See the comment paragraph on how to deal with the unsuported execution path)

Alternatively, you could declare `cell` as a `var` of type `UITableViewCell` outside of all if/else blocks, assign it to the appropriatey dequeued cell inside, (i.e., remove the `let` keyword if modifying the code above), and return it at the very end.

But you still need to make sure it is initialized before returning.

Comment: Got it. There are only 2 sections at max so indeed by removing the `if (indexPath.section == 0)` check, `return cell` becomes exhaustive and returning dummy `FriendCell` is not required.. Thanks a bunch for your help.

Answer (score 1):

if the method `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` is asynchronous, I think you can use `self.tableView.reloadData()` instead of `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    self.tableView.reloadData() 
})`

add `self.tableView.rowHeight = 50`

and you don't return your addfriendcell. you just return FriendsCell() at the last line. add the return cell.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if searching == true {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("AddFriendCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? AddFriendCell {
            let resultCell = userResults[indexPath.row]
            cell.configureCell(resultCell)
            return cell! //add the return
        }
    } else {
        if friendRequests.isEmpty ||  (indexPath.section == 1)  {
            if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FriendCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? FriendCell {
                let friendCell = friends[indexPath.row]
                cell.configureCell(friendCell)
                return cell! //add the return
            }
        } else {
            if (indexPath.section == 0) {
                if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FriendRequestCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? FriendRequestCell {
                    let friendRequestCell = friendRequests[indexPath.row]
                    cell.configureCell(friendRequestCell)
                    return cell! //add the return
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return FriendCell()
}
```

Comment: That's what I had initially and how I always did it... Just changed it back. Any ideas on the overlap?

Comment: you don't return you cell

Comment: @Rose: You should not return an empty (non-configured cell); see my answer to his previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34015225/433373

Comment: @NicolasMiari Could you please show how you would implement your suggestion for this scenario? I have been trying to declare a cell outside the scope of the conditions in order to return the configured cell, however that does not work

Comment: Like I said, the dequeue method never fails, provided `identifier` matches the `UITableViewCell` subclass registered with the table (programmatically or in IB). Just dequeue the appropriate type of cell depending on the case and cast it, configure it and return it.

Comment: @NicolasMiari what happens is that if I replace `return FriendCell()` with `return cell`, `cell` is not in scope, so I get `use of unresolved identifier`. Then, if I declare `var cell: UITableViewCell!` before all the conditions, and downcast with e.g. `as! AddFriendCell`, the cell remains a `UITableViewCell!` and doesn't have a `configureCell` function. I'm not sure how to work around this.

Comment: @EricJohnson try to add `self.tableView.rowHeight = 44`